# Post additional input to update ViewModel - adding quantity in shopping cart

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm developing a simple sort of shopping cart using Session state. I got everything working, but I try to add a functionality of adding additional units of the same item. I have a Cart class that carries a list of CartItems. Each CartItem has Product and its Quantity. The view with the GET method gets a nicely updated cart and Session (aside from quantities, which I aim to fix with the POST request).

I tried the path below, but the quantity is always stuck at 0. I saw a similar post here, which likely addressess same issue.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363813/why-isnt-my-viewmodel-updating](http://Why%20isn't%20my%20viewmodel%20updating?)

but it requires Knockout js, which I was not exposed to yet (and need to finalize my school project on short timeline). I will greatly appreciate if there are ideas around wihtout knockout. Below is a simplified code for clarity.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Show(CartViewModel cvm) 
{
Cart cart = (Cart)Session["Cart"];
cvm.CartItems = cart.CartItems;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

if (TryUpdateModel(cvm))
{
    foreach (CartItem c in cvm.CartItems)
    {
        sb.Append(c.Product.Name); // works
        sb.Append(c.Quantity); // always 0 :(
    }
}

return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

**View**

```
@model Project.ViewModels.CartViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
foreach (var item in Model.CartItems)
    {
        @item.Product.Name
        <img src="@item.Product.Image" alt="@item.Product.Name"/>

    @Html.EditorFor(i => item.Quantity)
    }
}

<input type="submit" value="Send" />

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of a `foreach` loop is generating duplicate `id` attributes (invalid html) and duplicate `name` attributes which have no relationship to your model. Yu need to use a `for` loop (property `CartItems` must be `IList<CartItem>`) or a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `CartItem`.

Using a `for` loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.CartItems.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CartItems[i].Name)
    <img src="@Model.CartItems[i].Product.Image" alt="@Model.CartItems[i].Product.Name"/>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.CartItems[i].Quantity)
}
```

This will generate the correct `name` attribute for property `Quantity`, for example

```
<input name="CartItems[0].Quantity" ...>
<input name="CartItems[1].Quantity" ...>
```

which will bind to your model